# Dynamically get the public path for a workbench package in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'd like to get the path to a package public directory (css etc) based on the package alias.

Is there anything already built into the laravel framework?

In other words something like:

```
public_path('myalias');
```

When I'm talking about alias, you would typically "alias" a module by adding the following within your service provider's boot method:

```
$this->package('namespace/package','alias_name');
```

For those wondering why someone might want to do this:

We are running a multi domain/subdomain application that makes use of a central piece of code for all of the domains and then specific packages per domain (I'll refer to them as funnels).

Each funnel has its own controllers that can possibly extend base controllers to implement their own functionality while re-using code where they can. They also have their own views.

The funnel refers to its own views by way of something like:
View::make('funnel::path.to.view')

The way we accomplish this is by doing some business logic on page load to only load the FunnelServiceProvider related to that particular domain and aliasing it to "funnel". This way our base controllers can also refer to funnel and not be tied to a particular packages views,includes,blocks etc.

My hope is to do something similar on the views so that I can simply call something like get_funnel_path() to get the path to the funnel that is currently being loaded.

The value could then be used to load css,js,images etc without worrying about the funnel path.

This would allow us to simply copy and paste views from one domain to the next without having to modify all of the paths in potentially multiple files. We could also make use of globally included files in all/most of the views.

An example of this might be the head. The head section should be the same for 99% of the files, however the path where it loads its resources should change based on the funnel.

We use the same naming conventions for css files as well as use sass, imports, merging for all of the funnels; so only the path needs to change.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *package alias* where is that defined? Or do you just mean the name? (`vendor/package`)

Comment: @lukasgeiter
Please see the above addition to the question.

Comment: I see. Well it's not exactly what you asked for but how about `public_path('packages/namespace/package')`?

Comment: yes that would be an option... I was hoping for something more self aware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this although it will only work with your own packages and require a bit of work. Because the alias is not really stored somewhere you can easily access you have to do that yourself.

First create some kind of class to store your package names in. I called mine `PackageManager`:

```
class PackageManager {

    private $packages = array();

    public function addPackage($fullName, $alias){
        $this->packages[$alias] = $fullName;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPublicPath($alias){
        if(!isset($this->packages[$alias])) return public_path();
        $path = 'packages/' . $this->packages[$alias];
        return public_path($path);
    }
}
```

Now let's register that class as a singleton in a service provider:

```
$this->app->singleton('packagemanager', function(){
    return new PackageManager();
});
```

Then, in every package you want to register, add this call in the boot method right next to `$this->package()`:

```
$this->app['packagemanager']->addPackage('vendor/package', 'alias');
```

After that you can do this anywhere in your application:

```
app('packagemanager')->getPublicPath('alias');
```

If you want a shorter syntax, add this helper function somewhere:

```
function public_package_path($alias){
    return app('packagemanager')->getPublicPath($alias);
}
```

And just do:

```
public_package_path('alias');
```

Comment: This will work, I was hoping for a more laravel-centric way of doing it. Will give the check if I don't see something along those lines. Thanks lukas!